# find $\lim_n a_n=(\frac{1}{k}+\frac{1}{n})^n$, where $k\in \mathbb{N}$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I know that $e=\lim_n (1+\frac{1}{n})^n$. How can I manipulate this to get the limit?

Answer (score 3):

You have $a_n = \frac{1}{k^n}(1+ \frac{k}{n})^n.$ We know that $$ \lim_{n\to\infty} (1+\frac{k}{n})^n = e^k$$ so $a_n\to e$ if $k=1$ and $a_n\to 0$ if $k\ge 2.$

Another way to think about it it is that while the limit $(1+1/n)^n$ is an indeterminate form $1^\infty,$ something like $(1/2+1/n)^n$ is of the form $(1/2)^\infty = 0$ which is not indeterminate.

Answer (score 1):

*Just another way using equivalents.*$$a_n=\left(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n=\frac 1{x^n}\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n\implies b_n=x^na_n=\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n$$
$$\log(b_n)=n\log\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)\sim n \times \frac{x}{n}=x\implies b_n\sim e^x\implies a_n \sim \frac {e^x}{x^n}$$ So, if $x < 1$, $a_n \to \infty$; if $x=1$, $a_n \to e$; if $x>1$, $a_n \to 0$ .